# Is there a word that has no nuance and refers to the literal property of something being new?

Tags: vocabulary, nuance

Sorry for the rather confusing title. I'm writing a research paper regarding COVID-19 and am trying to write a sentence along the lines of:

> The main challenge of building a COVID-19 domain QA model is the lack of datasets in this new domain.

The sentence wasn't written by me, but I want to change the last part "in this new domain" to something else that hints at the lack of available data due to the fact that we just haven't had COVID-19 in our lives for a long time.

Some example ideas I wrote are:

1. The main challenge of building a COVID-19 domain QA model is the lack of datasets due to the novelty of the domain.
2. The main challenge of building a COVID-19 domain QA model is the lack of datasets due to the nascence of the domain.
3. The main challenge of building a COVID-19 domain QA model is the lack of datasets due to the fact that COVID-19 is fairly new.

All three of them seem kind of meh to me. "Novelty" and "nascence" don't exactly capture my intention, as those two words usually have some sort of nuance to them and I simply want to state the literal fact that COVID-19 is new without any strings attached.

I've tried searching the Internet for some synonyms of "novelty" and "newness," but the results are also a little unsatisfactory and was wondering if someone here may know a better answer. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something more precise/factual, like "was first identified/characterized/described in 2019 / less than a year ago," etc?

Comment: One problem with all of your proposed sentences is that you use **domain** twice, and the second reference is awkward no matter what synonym of *new* you use. I would rearrange the construction of the sentence: *The main challenge with COVID-19 is building a QA model **in a new domain** where there is a lack of existing datasets.*

Comment: @JasonBassford Oh shit that's actually really good, thanks! I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score -1):

I’m not sure what you mean by ‘domain’ in this question.  I like your third option.

The disease is COVID-19. The virus that causes it is now called SARS-CoV-2.

The virus was initially called “a novel coronavirus” or “the novel coronavirus” before it was identified more specifically.  There are four kinds of coronaviruses, two of which affect animals other than human beings, and some of which cause the common cold.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus for more information. You can use Google scholar for articles on the topic published in 2020 for further insight into the terminology in use; the word ‘novel’ is in use in writing about the virus prior to its more specific identification.